# VIM: Sort by Function name

Tags: function, sorting, vim

I have a lot of functions in my menu.vim file.
Would it be possible to select them (by me) and sort them by function name?

p.e.
find lines from fun! or function!
to line endfun

find name of function and sort the whole block based on the name of function (from a-z)

Sometimes I have one line of comment above the function name.
Can it be taken with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be a bit tricky but here is a tentative way to do it:

- choose a substitution pattern that is not in your source file, like @@@
- `g/fun\%[ction]!\= /,/endf\%[unction]/ s/$\n/@@@`
- Then, select all one-liners and use `'<,'>sort /fun\%[ction]!\=/`
- `%s/@@@/\r/g`

Comment: @Benoit, great idea :)... but something doesn't work in my file. E486: Pattern not found: func\%[ction]!\=  ---> I did a test with 2 functions : 1)   function! s:LongerLessThen(type) --> endfun 2)   function! s:EmptyBeforeAfterRegex(type) --> endfun

Comment: @Benoit, How can I check this? I tried this: echo &magic --> output --> 1

Comment: @Remonn: funcction is not an alternative spelling for function. Therefore I suggest you autocorrect my own mistakes :)

Comment: @Remonn This is probably because Benoit forgot to add slashes around `endfun` pattern (and it should be `/endf/`, not `/endfun/`).

Comment: By the way, most of time single NULL byte is much less likely to be in a source file then any other ASCII and most unicode strings, so `@@@` should probably better be replaced with `\n`.

Comment: @ZyX: you're right, endfun was not a pattern here… and you are right about `\n` but afterwards, when you don't know how to revert back (need `/^J^J^J/`) it is not really simple.

Comment: @Benoit, @ZyX, I don't know what it does but it works with the slashes and @@@. Thank you both.

Comment: @ZyX: you can always feel free to edit my answers if you feel that they need improvement!

Comment: @Benoit The reason why I complained about `@@@` is that I also though that it is unlikely to be in normal source code and so used this sequence as a variable name in a number of code generators (search for format.vim (it generates a function that does the job as it will be faster) and frawor (it has DSL compiler and 'decorators', both use `@@@` as a variable name for different reasons)).

Comment: Old topic but im getting E486: Pattern not found: endf\%[unction]