# How to sort methods into alphabetical order in VIM?

Tags: vim

```
class MyClass

  def zzz
    # method body
  end

  def aaa
    # method body
  end

end
```

How would I get VIM to organise these into alphabetical order such that the definition of aaa precedes the definition of zzz?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM: Sort by Function name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618607/vim-sort-by-function-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can set up code folding e.g. by indentation, and close those functions/fold, then do it manuall with <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> then <kbd>p</kbd> but that is not an ideal solution with a large file.

It's not an easy task. You can set up some line-joining, e.g.:

1. put some specific comment/identifier before every first level `def`, like

   `# DEFINITION`

   `def zzz`

   `...`

   `end`

   `# END DEF`
2. then join those lines into one with some multiline regex magic (and/or column editing), using some placeholder which generally does not occur in your code.
3. then sort it via standard unix sort (e.g. visually select your joined lines, then

   `:'<,'>!sort`
4. then split on the inserted pattern...

Still less than ideal, but it can be done...

See [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5618692/11621).

Comment: Thank you for linking to my answer, and also +1 for the idea of using the folds.